# Only one image is displayed in the image carousel in bootstrap and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to display images in bootstrap carousel but am not able to loop. Only one image is shown but not sliding.Am using laravel in the back end. Please assist if you can this is the code.
This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  @foreach($images as $value)
                <li data-target="#imageCarouselIndicator" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
    @endforeach
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    
         <h3>{{$product->title}}</h3>
         @foreach($images as $image )
        <div class="item image {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
           <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img src="/images2/{{$image->filename}}" alt="{{$image->title}}">
          </div>
     </div>
      @endforeach
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#imageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#imageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
  
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
 @foreach($images as $image )
    <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <img src="/images2/{{$image->filename}}"/>
    </div>
@endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```